# What is a good strategy for killing Witches in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and I kept getting killed by a witch. Is there any good strategies for taking down a witch? I have tried going straight in and that did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Like many mobs in minecraft, the best way to take them down is from a distance. Using a bow and arrow is the most effective, but splash potions of harming can do the trick. If you have no access to either of those, I would recommend you just run from them unless you have an enchanted diamond sword.

The [wiki](http://minecraft.wikia.com/wiki/Witch) page has some info on what kind of potions they throw and how to take them down with sword

> A witch relies on using harmful potions, such as Poison, for
>   ranged attack. The best way to fight a witch is to get in close and
>   not let it get away. Keep hitting it, and it will fall quickly. Damage
>   must be consistently dealt to a witch in order to kill it, as it has
>   the ability to use healing potions to regenerate health.

Comment: *the best way to take them down is from a distance* while the wiki says otherwise... which one is now true? :)

Comment: haha good point. The wiki doesnt mention using a bow at all, but from my personal experience having a good bow that can shoot them down before they even aggro to you is better than trying to rush them.

Comment: Melee with milk buckets is best, though this question and answer are both highly opinionated.

Comment: Yeah I wont disagree. Ive always found using a bow is the best to kill most mobs. You can kill them from a distance, sometimes without them even seeing you. But I felt it would be good to include what the wiki says. Take it as you want. Like you said, the question kind of solicits opinionated answers.

Answer (score 0):

Taking them down from a distance with a bow is a good idea, or a splash potion. Don't knock them into lava or they will drink a potion of resist fire, and the lava will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Bring a Diamond Sword, if you have one.  Run away as fast as you can and the witch will chase you. Run about 5 to 6 meters and stop. The witch will then go up to you and kill it with a diamond sword.

---

Comment: Could you elaborate on that? It is rather vague, and as you will see on other post here, vague answer are not good.